# Replace white space with underscore of the file name under recursively

Tags: bash, macos, sed, replace, find

I have a hundred thousand files within a folder and under lots of subfolders.

There are something problems that many files start with space/end with space.

In this case, I would like to replace those spaces ( ) with an underscore (`_`).

However, my command seems to change all spaces within the path.

Example:

```
/Volumes/FolderA/Test 1/12345 Pro/12345 Pro .pdf
/Volumes/FolderA/Test 2/54321 Pro/ 54321 Pro.ai
/Volumes/FolderA/Test 3/ 33333 Pro /
```

After change: (changes all spaces, including the path)

```
/Volumes/FolderA/Test_1/12345_Pro/12345_Pro_.pdf
/Volumes/FolderA/Test_2/54321_Pro/_54321_Pro.ai
/Volumes/FolderA/Test_3/_33333_Pro_/
```

**What I want:**

```
/Volumes/FolderA/Test 1/12345 Pro/12345 Pro_.pdf
/Volumes/FolderA/Test 2/54321 Pro/_54321 Pro.ai
/Volumes/FolderA/Test 3/_33333 Pro_/
```

or

```
/Volumes/FolderA/Test 1/12345 Pro/12345_Pro_.pdf
/Volumes/FolderA/Test 2/54321 Pro/_54321_Pro.ai
/Volumes/FolderA/Test 3/_33333_Pro_/
```

As I have tested for many code, but no one can do what I want.
Here is some my Mac Terminal Coding:

```sh
find . -name '\ *' | while read f; do mv -v "$f" "$(sed 's/ /_/g' <<< "$f")" ; done

find . -name '*.pdf' | while read f; do mv -v "$f" "$(sed 's/ /_/g' <<< "$f")" ; done
```

Besides, is it possible to find the last occurrence of the space and to replace it?

Comment: When using "${f// /_}", it would not work recursively / changing the file path

Comment: Well, do you need `"$(sed 's/\(.*\) /\1_/' <<< "$f")`?

Comment: Wow, it's work on the files; Thanks a lot!! But I find that it seems not work for the folder start with space/ end with space yet; I try to investigate about it. Thank you so much

Comment: Could you please share the string that does not work with that sed command?

Comment: The not work folder is >> /Desktop/Test/ Test1 / <still keeping the space

After some testing, it seems would change all file space even it doesn't start with space

Example:
/Desktop/Test/abc 123.png -> /Desktop/Test/abc_123.png 

My Code with your Coding in this case:

find . name '\ *' | while read f; do mv -v "$f" "$(sed 's/\(.*\) /\1_/' <<< "$f")" ; done

Comment: I think I got it. Use `awk` - https://ideone.com/aFiK3t.

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to replace all whitespaces with `_` in the last `_`-delimited field**, you should use `awk` with `gsub`:

```
awk -F"/" 'BEGIN {OFS = FS}{{gsub("[[:space:]]+","_", $NF)}; print}' <<< "$f"
```

See [online demo](https://ideone.com/aFiK3t).

Here, `BEGIN {OFS = FS}` sets the output field separator to the field separator, i.e. to `/`.

The `gsub("[[:space:]]+","_", $NF)` line replaces all 1+ whitespace chunks (`[[:space:]]+`) in the last field (`$NF`) with underscores.

Comment: I find it would change all space of the filename to underscore in the subfolder/sub-subfolder even it is not start/end with space Eg. /Desktop/Folder/ABC 123.pdf -> /Desktop/Folder/ABC_123.pdf

Comment: @KenSham Have you tried `awk -F"/" 'BEGIN {OFS = FS}{{gsub("[[:space:]]+","_", $NF)}; print}' <<< "$f"`?

Comment: It simply replaces all file's space with underscore, but I only want replace those start /end with space. By the way, thank you for helping.

Comment: @KenSham It replaces whitespace chunks with `_` in the last item (after the last `/`), not in the whole file name.